# GMaps V2 snapping back to original position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, cross-browser, google-maps-api-2

Google Maps Pan Control in V2 does not work in *IE 9 and IE 10*.

Example: http://www3.telus.net/DougHenderson/Example0_v2.html

To reproduce the error - browse to the above link in IE9/10 and click on any of the 4 Pan controls (up, down, right, left) buttons on the top left. The map will snap right back to the default position.

This works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

I have tried searching SO and Google for this issue but could not find anything. Can someone help? Thanks.

I know V2 has been deprecated but I would appreciated if someone could shed some light on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is what I have found. The Pan functions in V2 is broken in IE9 and IE10. I got around it using setCenter function instead which still works in IE too. Sure you will not get the smooth transition from point A to point B with this function but it will not snap back like the Panto and Pandirection functions.

Answer (score 1):

[Version 2 of the API has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2). If functionality of v2 no longer works, you need to move to v3 and implement it there.